# Drag and Drop in a specific Area | Qt

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qtextedit

I have a MainWindow and inside the MainWindow there is QTextEdit. I want to do

> setAcceptDrop(true)

in QTextEdit only i.e, I do not want drop enabled in the MainWindow but it should be enabled in QTextedit.
I have seen some examples and everywhere I have found them to be implementing the drag and drop mechanism on the MainWindow so it automatically gets implemented on QTextEdit but I want it to be implemented in QTextEdit specifically.

I have attached an image of a sample application for the reference!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIVAI.png)

Comment: What type of element will you drop in the QTextEdit?

Answer (score 0):

`ui->textEdit->setAcceptDrops(true);`

Comment: But I will have to write functions like **dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)** and **dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)** , for which class should I write these functions? I will have to write it for Mainwindow right ?If I do so then it will activate a drop area on Mainwindow I guess.

Comment: You should be able to do it in any class you want. Check this out http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#drag-and-drop

Comment: I don't iunderstand! So should I create a class for QTextEdit object in UI ? If yes then please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: I can't tell whether or not you should with the information I have. Calling the setAcceptDrops method of textEdit won't affect your Mainwindow even if you call it from its class. you can call this->setAcceptDrops(false) to make sure of that.